# Adapt existing POCO instance to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: inotifypropertychanged

Say your code receives an instance from an external source, and you had no control over how the instance was created.  The instance does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Is there an adapter you can pass it to, as in:

```
var adapter = new ChangeNotifierAdapter( instance );
```

such that the adapter implements INotifyPropertyChanged and will thereafter raise its `PropertyChanged` event for all property changes of `instance`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that all changes to the instance will go via your wrapper, then you can use a proxy - either a [dynamic one](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=inotifypropertychanged%20dynamic%20proxy) or one generated at design time (nb: if you have to still expose the concrete class rather than an interface it'll have to be a dynamic proxy).

If that's not true (or even if it is, but changes to one property affect the value of another) then the only way to achieve this is via polling. The wrapper has to periodically poll all the properties of the object, determine which have changed and raise events accordingly. This is messy, and can be a serious battery drain on mobile devices.

Both suck of course. Mapping to an object that does implement it is generally a better solution.